# What happens if the number of partitions for a topic is changed?

Tags: apache-kafka

I didn't think it was possible to alter the number of topics for a partition, however I then found [this documentation page](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/operations-tools/topic-operations.html#increase-partitions-for-a-topic).

There is a section with the title *Increase Partitions for a Topic*.

If the number of partitions is *increased* what happens?

- To send data to a partition, a hash is calculated and the partition number is calculated using `hash(key) % number_of_partitions`. (as noted in the documentation)
- If the number of partitions increases (or changes) the hashed values of the keys for each message sent remain the same, but if the value of `hash(key)` >= `old_number_of_partitions` then messages will (probably) be placed on the *wrong* partitions when the number of partitions changes to the new value.
- Do old messages remain on the same partitions when more partitions are added?

As an aside, I have heard it said that once a topic is created the number of partitions cannot be changed (**Note 1**). However this doesn't appear to be quite correct, so I am trying to understand the details of what exactly happens when the number of partitions is increased.

- **Note 1:** Obviously, a new topic could be created with a different number of partitions and data could be streamed from the old topic to the new topic. The old topic could then be removed. This is not quite the same thing.

Comment: "the number of partitions can only be increased and not decreased." Yes.  There are too many questions in this post.

Answer (score 0):

The default partitioner will compute newer partitions since the modulo formula changes.

This will result in out of order data in some, or all, partitions, therefore may negatively affect topic compaction or ordered consumption. If you using null record keys, then these points won't be an issue.

When partitions are increased, you must manually place each replica on the brokers